# Mapped array error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've spent 3 days trying to write scopes in models. At this point i don't care about producing the optimum solution... i just want to get this to work. In a rails 3 app i have the following code in the controller.

```
@questions = Question.all
@ans = Answer.where(user_id = current_user.id)
@answers = @questions.map { |q| [q, @ans.find_by_question_id(q.id)] }
```

Each answer record has a question_id field so it can be linked to the appropriate question. I am trying to get the answers array to list out in the same order as the questions.

The following code in a view renders the answers but not in the correct order.

```
<% @ans.each do |q| %>
  <%=q.score%><br/>
<% end %>
```

I then changed the array to the mapped array which should produce the answers in the appropriate order.

```
<% @answers.each do |q| %>
  <%=q.score%><br/>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `score' for #<Array:0x10335ef90>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `q.score` you probably want `q[1].score`, since `q` is really a two-item array of the question and answer. The second item (`q[1]`) will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `q` is not an `Answer`, but an array containing both a `Question` and an `Answer`. So you could just change it to `q[1].score`. A nicer way is to break out the array in the block variables, like so (note the parentheses):

```
<% @answers.each do |(question, answer)| %>
  <%= answer.score %><br/>
<% end %>
```